# Display/Hide Element only in Mobile View During Specific Days/Hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We are trying to show/hide a phone number on a site in mobile view only given our client's business hours.

Ex. They are open from 9am to 5pm, Monday-Thursday and the number should display on all browser sizes, however when they are closed for the remainder of the time, the number should not display in mobile view, but remain displaying in tablet & desktop viewports.

Here is the javascript we are using - not formatted for days & times yet.

How should we make this work?

```
    var d = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var status = 'open';
    if (dayOfWeek > 2 && dayOfWeek < 6 && hour > 9 && hour < 20) {
    status='open';
    } else {
    status='closed';
    }
    if (status==='open') {
    document.getElementById("mobile-number-hide").style.display = 
    'block';
    } else {
    document.getElementById("mobile-number-hide").style.display = 
    'none';
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  You should include a small snippet of your html and css that is relevant to your problem.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think he don't know where to start. Well you can try this: `@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .bloc {display: none;
  }
}`. Now, you just need to apply the class `block` on the element you want to hide based on screen size

Comment: Before I get into the solution, I want to say that from a UX perspective, there are several reasons not to do this. What is the point of hiding the phone number when the business is closed? Do they not have a voicemail system? Just list the business hours and leave the numbers. What if the potential customer wants to write down the number for later, or give it to a friend. Are they going to know to check the website during business hours in that time zone?

Comment: Can you check `window.innerWidth < 640` in the case of status `closed` and hide the mobile number based on that.

Comment: Sorry - I suppose I never did pose a question. My question is how do we implement this?

We have a span element ID set to mobile-number-hide and the javascript code above placed in our CMS.

Comment: @zombiedoctor - I know it's not the best idea, but it is what our client wants. It's not a permanent feature just yet. We are A/B testing against the control.

Comment: I forgot to post my actual answer.. https://jsfiddle.net/6cbeam0u/

Note you also have to account for time zones, which is very tricky. The script as is, relies on the user's device timezone. 

Instead of writing my own handler for this, I used timezone.js

You mentioned mobile. Does the same requirement apply to desktop users? If it's only intended to hide for mobile users, then you will need to specify breakpoints in your CSS too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have solved our coding question. Here are the results:

```
var d = new Date();
var central_d = d.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Chicago"});
if (central_d.includes("PM")){
 var add_time = 12;
} else {
 var add_time = 0;
}
var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
var hour = parseFloat(central_d.split(', ')[1].split(':')[0]);
var hour = hour + add_time;
var status = 'open';
if (dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 5 && hour >= 8 && hour <= 20  || dayOfWeek == 5 && hour >= 8 && hour <= 17 || dayOfWeek == 6 && hour >= 9 && hour <= 13){
    status='open';
} else {
    status='closed';
}
if (status==='open') {
    vwo_$("#mobile-number-hide").vwoCss({"visibility":"show"});
} else {
    vwo_$("#mobile-number-hide").vwoCss({"display":"none !important"});
}
```

the last if else statement is VWO specific javascript

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using Javascript is that the time is based on the visitor's browser/timezone. Therefore 9pm in Australia is not the same as 9pm in the Americas.
You could use PHP instead which will take the time from your server instead. Ensure your server's timezone is setup in accordance to the business location.

PHP:

```
<?php
function hideOnTime(){
    $hideOnTime = '';
        if (strtotime(date('H:i')) >= strtotime('06:00') && strtotime(date('H:i')) <=                strtotime('20:00')){
    $hideOnTime = 'none';
    } else {
        $hideOnTime = 'block';
    }
    return $hideOnTime;
    }
?>
```

And this could be your inline CSS:

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 860px) {
.closed {
 display: <?php echo hideOnTime();?>;
}}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have also mentioned the time our client wants to base this off is central time zone (USA)

Comment: You can check your server's timezone first. Depending if it is shared or self hosted. And perhaps in your PHP you can declare this first: `date_default_timezone_set("America/Belize");` before all of the time handling. https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

> when they are closed for the remainder of the time, the number should
>   not display in mobile view, but remain displaying in tablet & desktop
>   viewports.

```
if (status==='open') {
    document.getElementById("mobile-number-hide").style.display = 
    'block';
    } else {
if ( window.innerWidth <  640 ) {
    document.getElementById("mobile-number-hide").style.display = 
    'none';
    }
}
```

The simplest way in your case.